# in R how to join 2 dataframe if one of the two column values in first dataframe match to one column value in second data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

suppose we have two data frame

```
df1=data.frame(col1=c("a","c","d"),
      col2=c("m","e","d")
      )


> df1
  col1 col2
1    a    m
2    c    e
3    d    d


df2=c(coll1=c("m","f","d"),
      coll2=c(2,4,5)
)


> df2
  coll1 coll2
1     m     2
2     f     4
3     d     5
```

is there direct way to left join df1 and df2 based on either if col1 or col2 of df1 match to value coll1 of df2. (without going through the left join twice).

desired result:

```
#first row : between 'a' and 'm' from df1, 'a' match to coll1 of df2
#second row : between 'c' and 'e' from df1, no value is match
#third row : the two value are match
df3
col1 col2 output
a    m      2
c    e     NA
d    d      5
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `match` with `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(output = coalesce(df2$coll2[match(col1, df2$coll1)], 
     df2$coll2[match(col2, df2$coll1)]))
```

-output

```
 col1 col2 output
1    a    m      2
2    c    e     NA
3    d    d      5
```

---

If we use `dbplyr`, can also make use of `sql_on`

```
library(dbplyr)
left_join(tbl_memdb(df1), tbl_memdb(df2), 
   sql_on = "LHS.col1 = RHS.coll1 OR LHS.col2 = RHS.coll1") %>% 
     select(col1, col2, output = coll2) %>% 
    collect()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  col1  col2  output
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a     m          2
2 c     e         NA
3 d     d          5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The solution you provided was exactly what I needed. I was also wondering if there is any ideas or suggestions for using the join function in R to retrieve multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: @islem can you try the update

Comment: I tested the second suggestion on my actual dataframe, it aligns perfectly with what I'm looking for!.
Thank you very much for your assistance @akrun